# Access Remote EJB in one Websphere profile from another WebSphere profile

Tags: websphere, jndi, rmi, initial-context, iiop

In short: I make a remote JNDI call for a stateless bean from one Websphere server to another (different profiles in different JVMs on the same machine) but after the call is done, the InitialContext gets changed and I can no longer access my local beans.

The situation is as follows:
A Websphere server Server1 has a complex application with many beans and also needs to access a stateless bean (BeanX) on Websphere Server2 that runs another application.
I have managed to access BeanX on Server2 using either of the two methods:

1. Connection via code:

   ```
   private static Context;
   static {
     Hashtable env = new Hashtable();
     env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, com.ibm.websphere.naming.WsnInitialContextFactory");
     env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "iiop://localhost:9101");
     try {
       ctx = NamingManager.getInitialContext(env);
       mgr = (RemoteBeanXManager) PortableRemoteObject.narrow(ctx.lookup("BeanXManagerBean/remote"), RemoteBeanXManager.class);
     } catch (NamingException e) {//logging
     }
   }
   ```
2. Connection via Webshere configuration
   Configured in Server1: Environment -> Naming -> Name Space binding -> New ... Indirect
   And introduced the required values, corresponding to the exposed bean from Server2.
   Provider URL: `corbaloc:iiop:localhost:9101`
   Initial context factory name: `com.ibm.websphere.naming.WsnInitialContextFactory`
   And then proceeded to obtain the bean in the code as if it was in my local context.

I removed security for RMI/IIOP for Outbound in Server1 and for Inbound in Server2, so that the servers can communicate.
The bean is exposed by Server2, the remote interface `RemoteBeanXManager` exists in a common package for both applications and the call goes through correctly.

The problem appears after the call, when subsequent EJB injections in **Server1** for its **local** beans return a `com.ibm.ejs.container.util.ExceptionUtil.NoSuchEJBException`

Basically, at the next `@EJB` annotation encountered, Server1 will throw:

> com.ibm.ejs.container.EJBNotFoundException: EJB named SomeOtherBean
>   not present in application My Enterprise Application.     at
>   com.ibm.ejs.container.HomeOfHomes.resolveEJBLink(HomeOfHomes.java:751)

What I managed to understand as I investigate, is that the `InitialContext` on Server1 is changed by the connection to Server2, and cannot 'reset' back after the call through the remote interface. I tried re-obtaining the `InitialContext` with the default settings after the remote manager is obtained, but to no avail.
I tried to add the optional configuration parameters:
com.ibm.websphere.naming.jndicache.cachename `providerURL`
com.ibm.websphere.naming.jndicache.cacheobject `none`

Still the same exception.

If you have any ideas on how to isolate/cache the context on Server1 so that it can resume normal operation after a RMI-IIOP call, please let me know

**Updated to add:**
When I comment out the code that performs the remote call, the application starts correctly, and all `@EJB` injections work.

In **Server2**, at the call of the method from Server1 - no exception, just these messages:

```
    [11/27/18 9:28:13:525 EET] 00000139 BeanXManagerB I com.my.app.manager.impl.BeanXManagerBean performTaskForServer1 End     
    [11/27/18 9:28:13:883 EET] 00000139 RegisteredRes E   WTRN0064E: An illegal attempt to commit a one phase capable resource in a subordinate transaction branch has occurred.    
    [11/27/18 9:28:13:920 EET] 00000139 FfdcProvider  W com.ibm.ws.ffdc.impl.FfdcProvider logIncident FFDC1003I: FFDC Incident emitted on D:\programs\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\profile2\logs\ffdc\Server2_db3b4f88_18.11.27_09.28.13.8878526370681854823401.txt com.ibm.tx.jta.TransactionImpl.prepareResources 467    
    [11/27/18 9:28:13:932 EET] 00000139 FfdcProvider  W com.ibm.ws.ffdc.impl.FfdcProvider logIncident FFDC1003I: FFDC Incident emitted on D:\programs\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\profile2\logs\ffdc\Server2_db3b4f88_18.11.27_09.28.13.9214065828085434219239.txt com.ibm.tx.jta.impl.TransactionImpl.prepareResources 1505
```

The complete stacktrace of **Server1**'s error is:
[*I thought it would be too long to post all the incident reports.* ]

```
    [11/27/18 9:28:13:946 EET] 0000011a DMAdapter     I com.ibm.ws.ffdc.impl.DMAdapter getAnalysisEngine FFDC1009I: Analysis Engine using data base: D:\programs\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\properties\logbr\ffdc\adv\ffdcdb.xml    
    [11/27/18 9:28:13:967 EET] 0000011a FfdcProvider  W com.ibm.ws.ffdc.impl.FfdcProvider logIncident FFDC1003I: FFDC Incident emitted on D:\programs\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\profile1\logs\ffdc\Server1_ede9c292_18.11.27_09.28.13.9411059231941807719848.txt com.ibm.tx.jta.impl.RegisteredResources.prepareResource 1216    
    [11/27/18 9:28:13:991 EET] 0000011a FfdcProvider  W com.ibm.ws.ffdc.impl.FfdcProvider logIncident FFDC1003I: FFDC Incident emitted on D:\programs\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\profile1\logs\ffdc\Server1_ede9c292_18.11.27_09.28.13.9683456920548561326798.txt com.ibm.tx.jta.TransactionImpl.prepareResources 467    
    [11/27/18 9:28:14:014 EET] 0000011a FfdcProvider  W com.ibm.ws.ffdc.impl.FfdcProvider logIncident FFDC1003I: FFDC Incident emitted on D:\programs\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\profile1\logs\ffdc\Server1_ede9c292_18.11.27_09.28.13.9913497264494769300154.txt com.ibm.tx.jta.impl.TransactionImpl.prepareResources 1505    
    [11/27/18 9:28:14:032 EET] 0000011a FfdcProvider  W com.ibm.ws.ffdc.impl.FfdcProvider logIncident FFDC1003I: FFDC Incident emitted on D:\programs\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\profile1\logs\ffdc\Server1_ede9c292_18.11.27_09.28.14.0285054752089388843670.txt com.ibm.ejs.csi.TranStrategy.commit 294    
    [11/27/18 9:28:14:039 EET] 0000011a FfdcProvider  W com.ibm.ws.ffdc.impl.FfdcProvider logIncident FFDC1003I: FFDC Incident emitted on D:\programs\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\profile1\logs\ffdc\Server1_ede9c292_18.11.27_09.28.14.036797394156202410033.txt com.ibm.ejs.container.EJSHome.createBeanO 1047    
    [11/27/18 9:28:14:044 EET] 0000011a FfdcProvider  W com.ibm.ws.ffdc.impl.FfdcProvider logIncident FFDC1003I: FFDC Incident emitted on D:\programs\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\profile1\logs\ffdc\Server1_ede9c292_18.11.27_09.28.14.0403016172875256112876.txt com.ibm.ejs.csi.EJBApplicationMetaData.createStartupBeans 6921    

    [11/27/18 9:28:14:044 EET] 0000011a EJBApplicatio E   CNTR0190E: The StarterBean startup singleton session bean in the app1.jar module failed initialization with exception:    
    javax.ejb.NoSuchEJBException: An error occurred during initialization of singleton session bean MY Enterprise Application#app1.jar#StarterBean, resulting in the discarding of the singleton instance.; nested exception is: javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException: nested exception is: javax.transaction.RollbackException    
        at com.ibm.ejs.container.util.ExceptionUtil.NoSuchEJBException(ExceptionUtil.java:540)    
        at com.ibm.ejs.container.EJSHome.createSingletonBeanO(EJSHome.java:3752)    
        at com.ibm.ejs.csi.EJBApplicationMetaData.createStartupBeans(EJBApplicationMetaData.java:959)    
        at com.ibm.ejs.csi.EJBApplicationMetaData.startedModule(EJBApplicationMetaData.java:680)    
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.EJBContainerImpl.stateChanged(EJBContainerImpl.java:4525)    
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl$ComparableDeployedObjectListener.stateChanged(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2652)    
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.stateChanged(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1178)    
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.fireDeployedObjectEvent(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:1558)    
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedModuleImpl.setState(DeployedModuleImpl.java:252)    
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedModuleImpl.setState(DeployedModuleImpl.java:248)    
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedModuleImpl.start(DeployedModuleImpl.java:707)    
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.start(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:1150)    
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:800)    
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplicationDynamically(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1450)        
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2311)    
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:436)    
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitImpl.start(CompositionUnitImpl.java:123)    
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:379)    
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.access$500(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:127)    
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl$1.run(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:654)    
        at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAs(ContextManagerImpl.java:5574)    
        at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAsSystem(ContextManagerImpl.java:5700)    
        at com.ibm.ws.security.core.SecurityContext.runAsSystem(SecurityContext.java:255)    
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.startCompositionUnit(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:668)    
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.startCompositionUnit(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:612)    
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1340)    
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)    
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:90)    
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)    
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508)    
        at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:83)    
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor63.invoke(Unknown Source)    
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)    
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508)    
        at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:287)    
        at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean$4.run(RequiredModelMBean.java:1263)    
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:666)    
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)    
        at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invokeMethod(RequiredModelMBean.java:1257)    
        at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invoke(RequiredModelMBean.java:1096)    
        at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:831)    
        at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:813)    
        at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl$1.run(AdminServiceImpl.java:1350)    
        at com.ibm.ws.security.util.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:118)    
        at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl.invoke(AdminServiceImpl.java:1243)    
        at com.ibm.ws.management.application.sync.StartDeploymentTask.startDeployment(StartDeploymentTask.java:249)    
        at com.ibm.ws.management.application.sync.StartDeploymentTask.fullAppUpdate(StartDeploymentTask.java:121)    
        at com.ibm.ws.management.application.sync.StartDeploymentTask.performTask(StartDeploymentTask.java:109)    
        at com.ibm.ws.management.application.sync.AppBinaryProcessor$ExpandApp.expand(AppBinaryProcessor.java:1770)    
        at com.ibm.ws.management.application.sync.AppBinaryProcessor.postProcessSynchronousExt(AppBinaryProcessor.java:811)    
        at com.ibm.ws.management.bla.sync.BLABinaryProcessor.postProcess(BLABinaryProcessor.java:599)    
        at com.ibm.ws.management.bla.sync.BLABinaryProcessor.onChangeCompletion(BLABinaryProcessor.java:476)    
        at com.ibm.ws.management.bla.sync.BinaryProcessorWrapper.onChangeCompletion(BinaryProcessorWrapper.java:109)    
        at com.ibm.ws.management.repository.FileRepository.postNotify(FileRepository.java:1938)    
        at com.ibm.ws.management.repository.FileRepository.update(FileRepository.java:1442)    
        at com.ibm.ws.management.repository.client.LocalConfigRepositoryClient.update(LocalConfigRepositoryClient.java:189)    
        at com.ibm.ws.sm.workspace.impl.WorkSpaceMasterRepositoryAdapter.update(WorkSpaceMasterRepositoryAdapter.java:667)    
        at com.ibm.ws.sm.workspace.impl.RepositoryContextImpl.update(RepositoryContextImpl.java:1998)    
        at com.ibm.ws.sm.workspace.impl.RepositoryContextImpl.synch(RepositoryContextImpl.java:1946)    
        at com.ibm.ws.sm.workspace.impl.WorkSpaceImpl.synch(WorkSpaceImpl.java:549)    
        at com.ibm.ws.console.core.action.SyncWorkSpaceAction$1.run(SyncWorkSpaceAction.java:284)    
        at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAs(ContextManagerImpl.java:5574)    
        at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAsSystem(ContextManagerImpl.java:5700)    
        at com.ibm.ws.security.core.SecurityContext.runAsSystem(SecurityContext.java:255)    
        at com.ibm.ws.console.core.action.SyncWorkSpaceAction.execute(SyncWorkSpaceAction.java:288)    
        at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(Unknown Source)    
        at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(Unknown Source)    
        at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(Unknown Source)    
        at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(Unknown Source)    
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)    
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)    
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1235)    
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:779)    
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:478)    
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)    
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:143)    
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:96)    
        at com.ibm.ws.console.core.servlet.WSCUrlFilter.setUpCommandAssistance(WSCUrlFilter.java:971)    
        at com.ibm.ws.console.core.servlet.WSCUrlFilter.continueStoringTaskState(WSCUrlFilter.java:518)    
        at com.ibm.ws.console.core.servlet.WSCUrlFilter.doFilter(WSCUrlFilter.java:339)    
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:197)    
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:90)    
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:969)    
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1109)    
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:4217)    
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl.handleRequest(WebAppImpl.java:2208)    
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:304)    
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:1030)    
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1817)    
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:382)    
        at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:465)    
        at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:532)    
        at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:318)    
        at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:88)    
        at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLReadServiceContext$SSLReadCompletedCallback.complete(SSLReadServiceContext.java:1833)    
        at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)    
        at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)    
        at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)    
        at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)    
        at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)    
        at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)    
        at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)    
        at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1909)    
    Caused by: javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException: nested exception is: javax.transaction.RollbackException    
        at com.ibm.ejs.container.BusinessExceptionMappingStrategy.mapCSIException(BusinessExceptionMappingStrategy.java:152)    
        at com.ibm.ejs.container.BusinessExceptionMappingStrategy.mapCSITransactionRolledBackException(BusinessExceptionMappingStrategy.java:613)    
        at com.ibm.ejs.container.EJSDeployedSupport.mapCSITransactionRolledBackException(EJSDeployedSupport.java:609)    
        at com.ibm.ejs.container.EJSContainer.postInvokeRolledbackException(EJSContainer.java:4392)    
        at com.ibm.ejs.container.EJSContainer.postInvokeForLifecycleInterceptors(EJSContainer.java:4584)    
        at com.ibm.ejs.container.SingletonBeanO.callTransactionalLifecycleInterceptors(SingletonBeanO.java:248)    
        at com.ibm.ejs.container.SingletonBeanO.initialize(SingletonBeanO.java:330)    
        at com.ibm.ejs.container.BeanOFactory.create(BeanOFactory.java:105)    
        at com.ibm.ejs.container.EJSHome.createSingletonBeanO(EJSHome.java:3738)    
        ... 101 more    
    Caused by: javax.transaction.RollbackException    
        at com.ibm.tx.jta.impl.TransactionImpl.stage3CommitProcessing(TransactionImpl.java:1279)    
        at com.ibm.tx.jta.impl.TransactionImpl.processCommit(TransactionImpl.java:1053)    
        at com.ibm.tx.jta.impl.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:974)    
        at com.ibm.ws.tx.jta.TranManagerImpl.commit(TranManagerImpl.java:439)    
        at com.ibm.tx.jta.impl.TranManagerSet.commit(TranManagerSet.java:191)    
        at com.ibm.ejs.csi.TranStrategy.commit(TranStrategy.java:866)    
        at com.ibm.ejs.csi.TranStrategy.postInvoke(TranStrategy.java:188)    
        at com.ibm.ejs.csi.RequiresNew.postInvoke(RequiresNew.java:118)    
        at com.ibm.ejs.csi.TransactionControlImpl.postInvoke(TransactionControlImpl.java:482)    
        at com.ibm.ejs.container.EJSContainer.postInvokeForLifecycleInterceptors(EJSContainer.java:4576)    
        ... 105 more    
    [11/27/18 9:28:14:051 EET] 0000011a FfdcProvider  W com.ibm.ws.ffdc.impl.FfdcProvider logIncident FFDC1003I: FFDC Incident emitted on D:\programs\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\profile1\logs\ffdc\Server1_ede9c292_18.11.27_09.28.14.0481845564063299454983.txt com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.EJBContainerImpl.stateChanged 6637
```

Answer (score 0):

`HomeOfHomes.resolveEJBLink` is normally used for `@EJB` annotations that are resolved locally; an `InitialContext` is not used, nor is a JNDI lookup performed. The code processing the `@EJB` skips JNDI entirely and locates the EJB directly in the EJB Container.  The fact the failure occurs after a remote lookup could just be a coincidence.

I recommend looking at the `beanName` parameter of the `@EJB` and verifying that the `beanName` does in fact match a bean name in the **same application**.  If the `beanName` parameter is of the format `myModule.jar#SomeOtherBean` or `myModule/SomeOtherBean`, then make sure the module name is correct as well.  The names `myModule` and `SomeOtherBean` must match the names on one of the CNTR0167I messages in `SystemOut.log`, in the **same application**.

For WebSphere, resolving an EJB based on the `beanName` parameter only works within the same application. If the `@EJB` is referencing an EJB in a different application, even if that application is on the same server process, then you must provide a binding that identifies the JNDI name of the referenced EJB.  The binding would be specified in one of the files, `ibm-ejb-jar-bnd.xml/xmi` or `ibm-web-bnd.xml/xmi`. A binding may also be provided during application deployment (and the deployment would add it to the appropriate `*bnd.xml` file).

If the `beanName` parameter does appear to be correct, and a JNDI lookup is occurring for the `@EJB` annotation, then you'll need to provide the full exception stacks for both the client and server side of the lookup, to better understand how the `@EJB` processes was re-directed to the wrong server. If this is occurring, then the `EJBNotFoundException` should appear in the Server2 logs, and then flow back to Server1, where it would be reported again; so exception stacks from both server1 and server2 would be needed to identify how the lookup was incorrectly routed.

Comment: Well, the application deploys without a hitch when I comment out the code that does the remote call. That is why I think that the `@EJB` has a correct `beanName`.

Comment: I will add more details in the post above, as the comment would become too long

Comment: The exception stack shows that parts of your application are not starting properly; specifically a singleton bean @PostConstruct.  This bean will not exist, and cannot be injected into other beans.  Likely the remote lookup and method call is causing a problem with app start.  I'd focus on fixing `WTRN0064E: An illegal attempt to commit a one phase capable resource in a subordinate transaction branch has occurred.`  Then your app should start properly, and the `@EJB` injection is likely to work.